# name of one part in electrical cables

Tags: cables, electrical

There is an extra plastic or wrapper piece at the end of the electrical cables. I asked one of my friends about it and he said its for insulation purposes but he does not know the technical name of it.
Can anyone kindly help me with what the technical name of this is?
See the photo to be more clear
[image]

Comment: strain relief grommet

Answer (score 9):

It is a cable "strain relief*.

These are designed to prevent the cable bending sharply where it enters the appliance otherwise the cores are likely to fracture internally or the insulation crack.

[image]

*Figure 1. A progressive strain relief*

The progressive strain relief gets thicker and more resistant to flexing the closer it gets to the point of entry into the appliance. Even with a strong pull on the cable the radius of bending at the point of entry to the appliance can be kept reasonably large while the weak end pulls almost in line with the direction of the pull.

Note also that in your photo a hanger has been incorporated into the strain relief. This provides a means of hanging the tool securely other than hanging by the cable. The cable is typically not designed for carrying mechanical loads.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments below and clearly visible on close examination of the photo (when not bleary eyed), that's a chuck key holder. It does, however, make a good place to hang the drill!

Comment: They are often found in the cable gland category.

Comment: "_Note also that in your photo a hanger has been incorporated into the strain relief_" Is it a hanger, or is it for holding the chuck-key?

Comment: It's a chuck key hanger. :]

Comment: You're both correct. I'm six hours out of my normal time zone and wide awake four hours early. More sleep required. Fixing now.

Comment: Although the part may have a strain relief integrated it may also just be a pure **bend protection** and the actual strain relief is inside the tools casing (squeeze hold by two screws). If the stain relief is opened the cable than can be pushed/pulled quite easily through the bend protection.

Comment: @Dampmaskin -- the chuck key hanger goes on the other end, so that you have to unplug the drill to use the chuck key.

Comment: +1 I might also add, the strain relief is often not a part per-se but is molded onto the end of the actual cable. The latter process makes it possible to add extra "features" such as the "tool-belt lanyard attachment hole" shown in the picture.. Also CMR filters can be integrated into the molding.

Answer (score 2):

Strain relief.

It's not really for extra insulation so much as to protect the cable by resisting bending where it could be stressed. That could lead to fractures in the wires.

Sometimes the part itself is called a "boot" because of its resemblance to rubber boots.

Answer (score 1):

Its purpose is mechanical protection to avoid damaging the cable by bending too tight.

I think the English term for that is just "bend protection" or "anti-kink".

(It also contains a rubber lobe with a hole to hold the spanner when not in use)